# Heroku rake error in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake

Seem to be getting the following error in my terminal. Any reason why this is not working?

```
 Running `rake` attached to terminal... up, run.7822
 ! 
 ! Error connecting to process
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably bumping up against connectivity issues.

Ensure it is, in fact, a network issue by trying to connect to heroku's servers `rendezvous.heroku.com:5000` and `s1.runtime.heroku.com:5000`. If so, you'll need to figure out where along the route you're getting snagged.

You can also try running your rake command in detached mode as a temporary workaround:

```
heroku run:detached rake some:task
```